# Singly linked list data structure design, implementation and unit testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, linked-list

Design a singly linked list data structure that supports following operations: `size`, `is_empty`, `value_at(index)`, `push_front`, `pop_back`, `insert(index , value)`, `erase(index)`, `reverse`, `value_n_from_end(n)`.

I am looking for code review and feedback on data structure design and best practices.

Singly Linked List Node Definition:

```
#ifndef SLLNODE_H
#define SLLNODE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

class SLLNode {
private:
  int m_value;
  SLLNode *m_next;

public:
  SLLNode(int val=0): m_value(val), m_next(nullptr) {}

  /* SLLNode(SLLNode& t)
  {
    if (*this != t) {
      m_value = t.m_value;
      m_next = t.m_next;
    }
   }*/

  void setValue(int value)
  {
    m_value = value;
  }

  int getValue()
  {
    return m_value;
  }

  void setNext(SLLNode  *nextNode)
  {
    m_next = nextNode;
  }

  SLLNode* getNext()
  {
    return m_next;
  }
};
#endif
```

Singly Linked List Implementation

```
#ifndef SLLIST_H
#define SLLIST_H
#include "SLLNode.hpp"

class SLList {
private:
  SLLNode *m_head;
  
public:
  //constructor
  SLList():m_head(nullptr), m_size(0) {}

  // build new node
  SLLNode* createNode(int value)
  {
    SLLNode *tmp = new SLLNode(value);
    return tmp;
  }

  void setHead(SLLNode *node)
  {
    m_head = node;
  }
  
  SLLNode* getHead() const
  {
    return m_head;
  }
  
  const int size() const
  {
    int count = 0;
    for (SLLNode *ptr = m_head;
     ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->getNext()) {
      ++count;
    }    
    return count;
  }

  // get last but one node 
  SLLNode* getTailButOneNode()
  {
    SLLNode *tmp = m_head;
    SLLNode *prev = nullptr;

    while(tmp && tmp->getNext()) {
      prev = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->getNext();
    }
    return prev;
  }

  //check empty
  bool is_empty() const
  {
    return (m_head == nullptr);
  }

  
  int value_at(int index) const
  {
    assert(i >=0 && i < size());
    
    SLLNode *tmp = m_head;
    int i = 0;

    while(tmp && i < index) {
      tmp = tmp->getNext();
      ++i;
    }

    if (tmp)
      return tmp->getValue();
    else
      return INT_MIN;
  }

  void push_front(int value)
  {
    SLLNode *item = createNode(value);
    assert(item != nullptr);
    
    if (m_head != nullptr)
      item->setNext(m_head);
    m_head = item;
  }
  
  void pop_back()
  {
    SLLNode *lastPrevNode = getTailButOneNode();
    SLLNode *lastNode = lastPrevNode->getNext();
    lastPrevNode->setNext(nullptr);
    delete lastNode;
  }

  int front()
  {
    if (m_head)
      return m_head->getValue();
    else
      return INT_MIN;
  }

  int back()
  {
    SLLNode *tmp = m_head;
    while(tmp->getNext() != nullptr) {
      tmp = tmp->getNext();
    }
    return tmp->getValue();
  }
   
  void insert(int index, int value)
  {
    SLLNode *node = createNode(value);
    if ( index == 0 ) {
      node->setNext(m_head);
      m_head = node;
      return;
    }

    SLLNode *tmp = m_head;
    SLLNode *prev = m_head;
    int i = 0;
    while(tmp && i < index) {
      prev = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->getNext();
      ++i;
    }
    node->setNext(prev->getNext());
    prev->setNext(node);
  }

  void erase(int index)
  {
    int i = 0;
    SLLNode *todelete;
    
    if (index == 0) {
      todelete = m_head;
      m_head = m_head->getNext();
      delete todelete;
      return;
    }
    
    SLLNode *tmp = m_head;
    SLLNode *prev = m_head;
    
    while (tmp && i < index) {
      prev = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->getNext();
      ++i;
    }

    todelete = prev->getNext();
    if (todelete->getNext())
      prev->setNext(todelete->getNext());
    else
      prev->setNext(nullptr);

    delete todelete;
  }

  void reverse()
  {
    SLLNode *tmp, *prev, *cur;

    cur = m_head->getNext();
    prev = m_head;
    prev->setNext(nullptr);
    while(cur != nullptr) {
      tmp = cur->getNext();
      cur->setNext(prev);
      prev = cur;
      cur = tmp;
    }
    m_head = prev;
  }

  int value_n_from_end(int n)
  {
    SLLNode *first = m_head;
    SLLNode *second = m_head;
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n) {
      first = first->getNext();
      ++i;
    }

    while(first->getNext()) {
      first = first->getNext();
      second = second->getNext();
    }

    return second->getValue();
  }
};

#endif
```

Unit Test Cases

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "SLLNode.hpp"
#include "SLList.hpp"

namespace {
class  SLLTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
  virtual void SetUp() {
    SLLNode *n1 = new SLLNode;
    n1->setValue(10);
    SLLNode *n2 = new SLLNode;
    n2->setValue(20);
    SLLNode *n3 = new SLLNode;
    n3->setValue(30);

    testlist.setHead(n1);
    n1->setNext(n2);
    n2->setNext(n3);
  }

  //virtual void TearDown() {}
  SLList testlist;
};

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLLNodeTest)
  {
    SLLNode n(10);
    EXPECT_EQ(10, n.getValue());
    EXPECT_EQ(nullptr, n.getNext());
    n.setValue(20);
    EXPECT_EQ(20, n.getValue());
    SLLNode *m = new SLLNode(100);
    n.setNext(m);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, n.getNext()->getValue());
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListConstructor)
  {
    SLList list;
    EXPECT_EQ(list.size(), 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(list.getHead(), nullptr);
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListCheckEmpty)
  {
    SLList list;

    EXPECT_EQ(list.is_empty(), true);
    EXPECT_EQ(testlist.is_empty(), false);
  }
  
  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListcreateNode)
  {
    SLList l;
    SLLNode *tmp = l.createNode(10);
    ASSERT_NE(tmp, nullptr);
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListPushFront)
  {
   SLList l;
   l.push_front(100);
   EXPECT_EQ(1, l.size());
   EXPECT_EQ(l.value_at(0), 100);
   l.push_front(200);
   EXPECT_EQ(2, l.size());
   EXPECT_EQ(l.value_at(0), 200);
   EXPECT_EQ(l.value_at(1), 100);
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListPopback)
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(2));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(0));
    testlist.pop_back();
    SLLNode *p;

    for(SLLNode *h = testlist.getHead(); h!= nullptr; h= h->getNext()) {
      p = h;
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(20, p->getValue());
    testlist.pop_back();
    for(SLLNode *h= testlist.getHead(); h!= nullptr; h=h->getNext()){
      p =h;
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(10, p->getValue());
  }

   TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListFront)
   {
    SLList l;
    l.push_front(10);
    EXPECT_EQ(l.front(), 10);
    l.push_front(20);
    EXPECT_EQ(l.front(), 20);
    l.push_front(30);
    EXPECT_EQ(l.front(), 30);
    }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListBack)
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(2));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(0));
    testlist.pop_back();
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.back());
    testlist.pop_back();
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.back());
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListInsert)
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(2));    
    testlist.insert(0,100);
    testlist.insert(2,200);
    testlist.insert(5,300);
  

    EXPECT_EQ(100, testlist.value_at(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(200, testlist.value_at(2));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(3));
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(4));
    EXPECT_EQ(300, testlist.value_at(5));
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListErase)
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(2));    
    testlist.insert(0,100);
    testlist.insert(2,200);
    testlist.insert(5,300);
    EXPECT_EQ(100, testlist.value_at(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(200, testlist.value_at(2));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(3));
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(4));
    EXPECT_EQ(300, testlist.value_at(5));
    testlist.erase(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(0));
    testlist.erase(2);
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(2));
    testlist.erase(3);
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.back());
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListReverse)
  {
    testlist.reverse();
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_at(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_at(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_at(2));
  }

  TEST_F(SLLTest, SLListValueFromEnd)
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(30, testlist.value_n_from_end(0));
    EXPECT_EQ(20, testlist.value_n_from_end(1));
    EXPECT_EQ(10, testlist.value_n_from_end(2));
  }
  
}//namespace

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Code will not compile, `m_size`not defined but used in ctor. In general, when building data-structures in C++, try to mimic the API of STL. See `forward_list` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.I missed to clean up m_size. I will take a look on forward_list.

Answer (score 1):

## Make it look exactly like `std::forward_list`

As `Chintan` mentioned, the standard library already has a singly-linked list implementation named [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). It would be nice if you follow that API exactly. Most importantly:

## Make it generic

Your list only works for `int`s. What you want a singly-linked list of `float`s, `std::string`s or any other type? You don't want to reimplement everything for every possible type. If you make `SLList` a template you can avoid this.

## Avoid manual memory management

Instead of using manual calls to `new` and `delete`, prefer using a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage memory for you. This avoids mistakes like forgetting to `delete` memory.

## Missing and inconsitent error checking

Some functions, like `back()`, derefence `m_head` without checking if it's `nullptr`. This will cause a crash when called on an empty list.

Some functions use `assert()` to check if a value is in range. But `assert()` is a no-op if `NDEBUG` is defined, which many build systems will automatically set for release builds. In others you check and return a value indicating an error. It would be great if you have a consistent way to check for and report errors.

Note that it is also fine to just *document* that certain functions are only allowed to be called on non-empty lists, or with indices that are within the range of the list. In that case, you don't have to do any error checking, although using `assert()` will allow bugs in code using `SLList` to be caught more easily.

## Don't reuse the value type to return errors

In `value_at()` and `front()` you return `INT_MIN` if the list is empty or you ask for an out-of-range index. But what if you legitimately stored `INT_MIN` in the list? Then it is no longer possible to distinguish between success and failure.

Find a way to signal an error condition, for example by `throw`ing an exception. Alternatively, return a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

## Don't allow the user to break the list

If someone calls `setHead()` then the original head node and potentially more nodes linked to it will no longer be reachable, but still allocated in memory. You could use `std::unique_ptr` to have it automatically freed, but that will cause issues if you set the head to any existing node in the list. It's much better to remove any functions that allow direct access to the list structure.

Alternatively, have a look at `std::forward_list`'s [`merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/merge) and [`splice_after()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after) member functions for how to cut and rearrange lists.